# labbook figure numbering

Tags: floats, numbering, koma-script, labbook

I am using the `labbook` document class which is based on scrbook. `labbook` doesn't number the chapters, but the figure numbering still behaves the way it was in `scrbook`: it's not running, but each chapter starts with "Figure 1". I tried

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{addchap}
```

but I get the error that `addchap` is not a counter (which absolutely makes sense). How can I get running figure numbering throughout the document?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{labbook}
\usepackage[]{graphicx} 
\begin{document}

\labday{Monday}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{Figure1.jpg}
\caption{Figure1}
\label{fig:Figure1}
\end{figure}

\labday{Tuesday}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{Figure2.jpg}
\caption{Figure2}
\label{fig:Figure2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `figure` counter is tied to the `labday` counter (while `\addchap` is the macro used to add another `\labday` and therefore does not constitute a counter). So, using

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr
\counterwithout{figure}{labday}
```

provides running figures from `labday` to `labday`.